# Functions and Stored procedures marked Invalid after entity changes

Tags: sql

I have a query for invalid stored procedures/functions after update to the tables.

Let's say we have a `Department` table (`PK:DeptNum,DeptName`) and `Employee` table (`PK:EmpNum,FK:DeptNum,Name,..`).

I make a stored procedure or function to reference `Department` table. Everything works fine. One day, I add a new column to `Department` table making it (`PK:DeptNum,DeptName,DeptPhone`).

Is it going to make my stored procedure invalid when the only entity added is `DeptPhone` which has no dependency on `Employee` table?

Thanks.

Comment: This is considered a *good* thing.  You need to recompile the stored procedures, functions, triggers, and views that refer to the table.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.